# Hot to remove Large space between grids

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to show some ads in a thumbnail but there is a large space betweeen them ..have a look[image]

I am using bootstrap thumbnails to show products.

```
                echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                          <div class="thumbnail">
                             <img src='.$source.' 
                             alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                          </div>
                          <div class="caption">
                             <h3>'.$title.'</h3>
                             <p>Price:Rs.'.$price.'</p><br>
                             <p>
                                <a href="'.$adress.'" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">
                                   View
                                </a> 
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">
                                   Update
                                </a> 
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">
                                   Delete
                                </a>
                             </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>';
```

CSS Bootstrap:

```
element.style {
}
@media (min-width: 992px)
.col-md-3 {
width: 25%;
}
@media (min-width: 992px)
.col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.col-sm-6 {
width: 50%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
float: left;
}
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
}
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
}
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
user agent stylesheetdiv {
display: block;
}
Pseudo ::before element
:before, :after {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
Pseudo ::after element
:before, :after {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
Inherited from body
body {
font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #333;
background-color: #fff;
}
Inherited from html
html {
font-size: 10px;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
html {
font-family: sans-serif;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Please help me to remove large space .The items are not in line.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: for this you can decrease margin associated with them.

Comment: @JayBlanchard How to remove large space b/w grid

Comment: @AZT I hav checked but there it didn't help

Comment: then there must be some padding present If not then please post your code including CSS

Comment: I want to put the last thumbnail below the first one

Comment: @AZT I hav already did below the picture

Comment: You need to add your CSS.

Comment: @JayBlanchard actually I am using bootstrap I have not customized it.

Comment: I have added the css.

Comment: Have tried changing the padding-right values? Additionally open the browser's developer tools and examine the elements. You can adjust values in the browser to see the effect and then transfer those values to your CSS files.

Comment: Yes I did it but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the particular grid:

```css
padding: 0
```

Comment: create a seperate css class giving a code "padding: 0 !important;"

Answer (score 0):

You will need to review your HTML structure before anything.

After refactoring your code, if you have the same issue use this:

```css
.grid-gap {
 gap: 1rem; !important
}
```

This will override Bootstrap css property by yours properties.